# SQL Server: where to check user/groups permission on sql-level?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I got a SQL Server database, where users are logged with windows credentials. I'm trying to look at users and groups permissions (reader, db_owner, etc) on SSMS.

I'm not sure if i can get that info on Security, or Roles. It seems i'm looking in the wrong place.

Could somebody point me on the right direction?

Thanks,

ps: edit: this is the screen i'm looking for
[image]

Comment: If you run `sp_helplogins` at your `master` database, you will get the results you need. This would save you time of going into each login through the GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Security -> Logins -> double click on needed user -> go to User Mapping -> click on needed user on "Users mapped to this login:" form

Comment: Actually, you'd want to click on the User Mapping to see the screen above.